# How to get M2.2 Customer Session in external App on same server

Tags: magento2

I am unable to get M2.2 customer session in an external app on same server  (where I had object Manager imported directly and its working fine) code in external Laravel App is as follow.

```
$state = $this->_objManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State'); 
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$customerSession = $this->_objManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
var_dump($customerSession->isLoggedIn());exit; // printing false either customer is logedin
```

I have multi web site & i already have cookie domain setting  like `.domain.com`
In M1 it was working fine

Comment: I'm glad this doesn't work... why would you want to do that?!

Comment: just want to get customer session in Laravel app to cross verify that customer is login